# Reading string with FS returns this Error: Unexpected token r in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing, fs

I have a string, not an object, nothing yet, but I need to get that data and the only way I've been able to get that is by doing JSON.parse on the readFile data with node's FS built-in module.

```
fs.readdir('./Names', (err, files) => {
  files.forEach(file => {
    fs.readFile(`./Names/${file}`, (err, data) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      var string = JSON.parse(data)
      console.log(string)
    })
  });
})
```

That's my code for now. I have all the data in there properly, for a brief explanation the fs.readdir gets the names of all the files and then reads them but I am having an issue reading the files since they aren't objects and it'd be very hard to turn a lot of .txt's into objects all at once without a script which would then lead back to this problem.

Is there any other way I could transform the data part of the object (which is a Buffer in NodeJS/JS) back into a string that's readable?

Comment: It would be helpful to include what the content of the file is, but the error is quite clear, you're not parsing JSON. `fs.readFile()` will return a buffer in `data` when you don't specify an encoding, but if you want a string you can either specify an encoding (probably `utf8`) or call `data.toString('utf8')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Patrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1541563/patrick-roberts) mentioned, the `data` returned is buffer, so you need to convert it to string or let the API does that for you by passing the encoding, like

```
fs.readdir('./Names', (err, files) => {
    files.forEach(file => {
        fs.readFile(`./Names/${file}`, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            // now uncomment this only if your data is JSON formatted
            // var string = JSON.parse(data)
            console.log(data)
        })
    });
})
```

Reference: [fs.readFile](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback)